Include or RevInclude on Cardinality 0..*
Using this tutorial:
https://github.com/hapifhir/fhir-tutorial/blob/master/Search_References_ChainHasIncludeRevinclude/lesson.md#reverse-include-_revinclude-1
and this image
Include and Reverse Include Image

When it is a parent:child relationship, it is straight forward to know the _include and _revinclude "direction".
Specimen             Include->          Patient
Patient              Include->          Organization

Organization         ReverseInclude->   Patient
Patient              ReverseInclude->   Specimen

When the relationship is "M:N"
AND
one side is composed of many FHIR-Resource-Types
Let's use:
https://www.hl7.org/fhir/patient-definitions.html#Patient.generalPractitioner
as an example:
Would it be:
Patient  Include->        generalPractitioner  (and all three of these come along for the ride -> Organization | Practitioner | PractitionerRole)

or
Patient  ReverseInclude-> generalPractitioner  (and all three of these come along for the ride -> Organization | Practitioner | PractitionerRole)

OR
Patient              Include->          Organization
Patient              Include->          Practitioner
Patient              Include->          PractitionerRole

OR
Patient              ReverseInclude->           Organization
Patient              ReverseInclude->           Practitioner
Patient              ReverseInclude->           PractitionerRole

OR
am I just way off ? ?
======
But one issue I see:
Patient              Include->          Organization (as generalPractitioner)

would conflict with the "normal"
https://www.hl7.org/fhir/patient-definitions.html#Patient.contact.organization
and also managingOrganization
https://www.hl7.org/fhir/patient-definitions.html#Patient.managingOrganization
====
the "spec" below for convenience.
Patient.generalPractitioner Element Id  Patient.generalPractitioner
Definition   Patient's nominated care provider. Cardinality 0..*
Type    Reference(Organization | Practitioner | PractitionerRole)


When you retrieve resources other than the ones that match your search criteria, the only way you can do so is by using a defined SearchParameter that exists either on the resource you're searching against, or on some other resource that points to one of the resources included in your search set.
_include allows you to search using SearchParameters defined in the current resource.  So, for example, you could say _include=Patient:organization which would retrieve the managingOrganization associated with the Patient.
_revinclude allows you to search using SearchParameters defined in the desired resource that points to a resource included in your search criteria.  So you could say _revinclude=Provenance:target:Patient to include all of the Provenance instances that point to the patient.
You couldn't use _revinclude to return Organizations associated with the Patient because Organization doesn't have any SearchParameters of type Reference that can point to Patient.  (FHIR tries very hard to make sure that relationships are expressed in only one direction - Patient points to Organization, but Organization doesn't point to Patient.)
The Patient search parameter 'organization' is defined as based on the path Patient.managingOrganization.  It will not search against Patient.contact.organization.

Ok.  The answer helps in the "Patient _include Organization" but "Organization _revinclude Patient" is not a "legitimate definition" because the Organization does not have a "childPatients" reference property. .. I got that.  (And I embedded the tutorial image in the above question... which now I think it a little off.

But the https://www.hl7.org/fhir/patient-definitions.html#Patient.generalPractitioner is still throwing me off.  As it is a search-parameter, but is composed of 3 different underlying FHIR resources.

The tutorial has this:
/Organization?_id=OR1_revinclude=Patient:organization&_revinclude:iterate=Speciment:patient

Agree that the diagram is misleading.
Patient.generalPractitioner is an element on Patient that has a type of Reference and the Reference can point to 3 different resources.
_revinclude:iterate=Specimen:patient means that it'll include Specimens that point to the Patient.

I should have cut off the last part of the example URL.  The part I was trying to emphasize on the tutorial was : /Organization?_id=OR1_revinclude=Patient:organization             Is this legitimate?  (the value of the _revinclude to be clear) ....  Based on their diagram it is legitmate, but based on your feedback, I don't think so.

It would have to be OR1&_revinclude, but otherwise yes.  Patient has an organization search parameter (that searches on Patient.managingOrganization).  The search would return the Organization with the id 'OR1' and would return all patients listing that as their managing organization.  The only challenge is there could be 10k+ patients that match, and there's no ability to page on 'included' resources.  So it's probably not a wise query to run in many situations.  (And some servers might refuse to return the result set due to size.)

Ok.  and agreed that a child bringing back their singular parent (Patient bringing back their Org) is trivial to the parent bringing back N:children .. which could turn into "way too much" very quickly.
